# Calculating field due to induced charges at exterior of conductor

Tags: conductors

We have an arbitrary hollow shaped conductor, with small thickness. Suppose we place a charge q at any arbitrary location within the hollow shaped conductor. By Gauss's law there will be a total charge on the inner surface −q. Since the conductor is neutral there will be a charge of +q on the outer surface.

Is it true that considering the contribution of field from the charges induced on the inner surface and the charge kept inside the conductor only, the field is zero everywhere outside the conductor? In different words, is the field at any point outside the conductor due to only the induced charges developed at the outer surface?
Please provide mathematical  reasons as well.

Thanks!

[The left body represents the hollow conductor with charge q placed at any arbitrary position inside the conductor.

The body X represents the charge distribution of inner surface and charge in initally kept inside. The body Y represents the charge distribution induced on the outer surface of the the conductor. My question is that for calculating the field at P(arbitrary point), due to the hollow conductor, we use the suporposition principle, it is equal to the sum of the electric field vectors due to X and Y, but is the field due to X zero, hence the only contribution is due to the Y, the charges developed on the outer surface]

[image: diagram]

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/644263/contribution-of-inner-induced-charges-to-the-electric-field-outisde

Comment: @OskarSkog i did not get a  mathematical proof there, so i asked it here, is this not allowed? sorry if it is not allowed, i will delete this post

Comment: @green_32 Please show an example of your "arbitrary hollow shaped conductor" and the placement of the interior charge. I think it's kind of clear what you are asking. But a diagram helps remove any doubt. I may not be understanding your setup, but it seems to me that if you take a Gaussian surface outside of the conductor, that it does enclose a net charge. Are you saying it does not? If you are saying it does *not* enclose net charge, then I'm certain I need a diagram to see what you are talking out.

Comment: @jonk, i have added few details hope it removes any doubt

Comment: @green_32 Oh. I think you understand things okay and it's a very simple situation then. Yes, charge **q** is canceled by the charge on the interior surface. But the charge on the outside is not canceled. So point **p** will observe a field due to the exterior surface. Of course, inside the metal shell -- in the metal itself that exists between the inside surface and the outside surface, the net field is everywhere zero.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematical (or logical) explanation is quite simple , if we analyse the problem closely -

**Let's assume outside surface induce charges (Y)=0** , because these are not matter of concern , so now we have two different remaining charge configuration one charge inside the conductor and second induced charge on the inner surface of conductor and after that there is no charge present as we move outside the inner surface (away from origin).

Now we know outside the inner induced surface  there is always a **metallic part** of conductor exist no matter what is width of conductor and due to this metallic part we can surely say That there would be Zero electric field in this part at steady state.

Therefore one of the obvious /possible electric field function outside the inner induce surface would be **$$\vec E=0 $$for all (x,y,z) belongs to region outside the inner surface**

But is there any other possible electric field function possible (outside the inner induce surface) ?

But

if there would be any such function exist then it should be of the form **$$\vec E=0 $$ for (x,y,z) belongs to metallic region  outside the inner induce surface** and  **$$\vec E=\vec f(x,y,z) $$where f is some arbitrary function and (x,y,z) belongs to region outside the metallic region** .

But we know that electric field function due to continuous charge distribution (inner surface charge) and point charge are well behaved algebraic vector function (in region of interest) and addition of these two vector functions should also be a well behaved algebraic vector function but above
Electric field function is a peicewise vector function that is why such functions are not possible .

Hence we left with only function i.e  **$$\vec E=0 $$for all (x,y,z) belongs to region outside the inner surface**

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  but I didn't understand few things, how can we say that the potential is zero at the surface if the electric field is zero, shouldnt we call it an equipotenital surface? Second, assuming V=0 at the surface and at infinite, doesn't the uniqueness theorem gurantee that there is a unique function V(x) which satisfies it only, how can we say that V(x) is zero for all x between region of infinity and the conductor?

Comment: Your 1st point is true that I shouldn't assume it at 0 potential , but in 2nd point if both boundary condition is Zero potential boundary  then one of the possible solution of Laplace equation is V(x)=0 but from uniqueness theorem if we got one possible solution then it will be only solution although second point is of no use if 1st point is not valid , so I'll edit my answer hopefully it will give some insight .

Comment: thanks, but can you please explain   what you mean by well behaved, if it means continous then , isnt it possible  for a peicewise functions to be continous as well? for eg consider a uniformly charged hollow  sphere, it  is 0  for r is less than or equal to R( here radius of sphere ), and for r greater than or equal to R is 1/r^2 dependence, it is a piecwise function as well

Comment: @ well behaved in this context is its curl and divergence do not blow up in our region of interest . and  in your example (piecewise function)  , piecewise function is due to surface charge  of conductor  which separates both regions while in previous case there was no charge present in region of interest , that's the whole point of the argument

Comment: I agree that E needs to be zero when the outer induced charges are zero, but if it were non zero then will the electric field due to the inner induced  and the charge necessarily be zero ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it true that considering the contribution of field from the charges induced on the inner surface and the charge kept inside the conductor only, the field is zero everywhere outside the conductor? In different words, is the field at any point outside the conductor due to only the induced charges developed at the outer surface? Please provide mathematical reasons as well.

Yes, this is true. I think it is more clear to say it the second way you did, which is that outside the conductor, the electric field is due only to the charges on the outside surface of the conductor.

I will prove this using superposition and the uniqueness theorem. First consider a conductor which is hollow, like the one you pose, but instead of having an outer surface, extends to infinity. The charge +q in the hollow region will induce a charge -q on the inside surface, and the electric field will be zero everywhere from that inside surface out to infinity. So we know that if we take away the conductor and leave that charge distribution in place, in produces this field that is zero everywhere outside the inner conductor surface.

Next consider a different problem that has the outer surface of the original conductor, has no hollow region (it is solid all the way through), and has a net charge +q. This charge will exist only on the outside surface, and will create a field that is zero everywhere inside that surface, but non-zero outside. Now take away the conductor and leave the charge distribution, and we know what the field produced by that charge distribution is.

We know that each of these problems satisfies Poisson's Equation, and so the superposition of them also satisfies Poisson's equations. It gives the desired fields in all three regions. By the Uniqueness Theorem, it is the one and only solution to the hollow-conductor problem.

Therefore the fields on the outer surface of the conductor are the only ones that contribute to the field outside the conductor, and they contribute nothing to the field inside the outer surface of the conductor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but isnt the field due to the charge distribution consisting of inner induced charges and the charge kept inside non zero in the conducting material,  since the outer induced  charges  contribute for the field in the conducting material  as well,  and also can you please elaborate on how we can extend this zero solution region to infinity? Thanks

Comment: The field due to the charges on the outer conductor do not in fact contribute to the field inside the conductor, but you make a good point that my first version of the answer has not proven that point. I will edit to prove that point.

Comment: I have now edited (rewritten, really) my answer to prove the point you raised.

Comment: @green_32 note that a "Faraday cage" cannot shield net-charge.  They can only shield dipoles (such as EM sources, AC magnets, etc.)    On the other hand, the LOCATION of the charged particle inside your conductive surface is "invisible" to the outside world!  Place it in different spots inside, and the external field does not change.  (So, heh, the Faraday cage is "shielding" the particle's location, even though the e-field caused by the net-charge is not blocked.)

Comment: @rpm2718,Thanks for explaining,  So is it true only for infinite conductors ? In the first case of your answer, since the outer surface of the conductor extends to infinty, then so will the inner surface (small thickness), if we superimpose,  the first and second charge distributions,  we would get that the inner charges of the surfaces are infinetly spread out, while the outer charges are bound to a fixed region, so how does it prove for a bounded inner surface charge distribution?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your question, but this proof applies to finite conductors. In the first case, we fixed the inner surface at the original inner surface and let only the outer surface go to infinity. So the conductor gets infinitely thick. Then we imagine taking the conductor away and leaving the charge distribution in place. So we know what field that charge distribution produces. Then we move on to the second problem, and make a similar argument, except we fix the outer surface and remove the hollowed out region. Does that help?

Comment: @rpm2718, yes thanks it helps, but when we extend the outer surface to infinity, the metallic region must have zero field, but how can we say that the field due to the inner charges is zero? There is contribution from outer surface as well to the field inside the metallic region,right? So there is a possibility that there is an equal and opposite fields due to the outer surface and due to the inner surface charge and point charge to cancel the field zero inside the metallic region, but not both of them are individually are zero

Comment: As the outer surface goes to infinity, those charges do not contribute to the field anymore because they are infinitely far away, and there is only a finite amount q of charge.

Comment: @rpm2718, but the thickness is also infinte , so can we comment about the field due to a charge distribution placed at infinty from origin let it be  a point inside the conductor, at a distance which is also infinte?

Comment: Yes, we certainly can. The contribution to the field from any element of charge on that surface falls off as the square of the distance to any point. If the charge density were fixed, we would have a problem, because the total amount of charge would also be growing, but since the total charge is what is fixed, then that \$\frac{1}{r^2}\$ falloff sends the field contribution to zero from the outside surface charges.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126529/discussion-between-rpm2718-and-green-32).

Answer (score 0):

The field can't be zero outside the conductor.

---

Consider an infinite cylindrical conductor empty inside, of radii (radiuses) R1 and R2, where R2 > R1.

Put the charge +q within the conductor at z = 0.

The charge +q will induce a charge −q on the inner surface R1.

The charge -q will induce a charge +q on the outer surface R2.

Consider a Gauss cylindrical infinite surface of radius R3 where R3 > R2 that embraces the conductor.

Apply Gauss' law on that surface.

Φ(E) = +q / ε0

you get that the overall flux Φ(E) can't be zero on that surface.

That means that, somewhere on that surface, E is not zero.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i wanted to ask for the electric field due to induced charges at the inner surface and the charges kept inside only, excluding the contribution from charges developed at the outer surface  of the conductor, the flux would be zero due to this body ( charges induced in inner  surface and charge q kept inside only) but what about the electric field ?